# How to convert strings from a file in this format to a number array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

i have a text file like this

**.txt**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

and i would like to view this as an array in python  this is what i have so far

**python file**

```
file_board = open('index.txt')
board = file_board.read().split(',')
print board
print len(board)
```

**output**

```
['[[1', ' 2', ' 3]', ' [4', ' 5', ' 6]', ' [7', ' 8', ' 9]]\n']
9
list index out of range
```

so what i want todo is some how make this in to a 2D array  for manipulation

**Note** I would like to do this without any external libraries, build in libraries are fine

by the way i would like to write this back to a new file
in the format of

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: welcome to SO! have a look at this post, i think it has the answer you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163024

Comment: updated my question @slider

Comment: updated my question @MCO

Comment: updated my question @AuroraWang

Comment: Your output and the text file are inconsistent. If your text file was really how you say it is, the output would just split at every comma, producing `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

Comment: @connectyourcharger thats the output i get
`['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8', ' 9\n']`
`9`
`list index out of range` 
you could try it your self

Comment: The output from your code is `['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8', ' 9\n']` **not** what you say it is in your question.

Answer (score 1):

@dlink's answer is OK, but to be safe you may want to use `ast.literal_eval` to prevent security issues:

```
import ast

file_board = open('index.txt')
board = ast.literal_eval(file_board.read())
print board
print len(board)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
str = '[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]'
data = eval(str)
for rec in data:
    print rec
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

If you want a 2D array (You edited your question).  You can use regex to remove the '[' and ']' and spaces.

```
import re
str2 = re.sub('[\[\] ]', '', str)
print str2
```

output
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9